# How to get Column Name With Zend DB

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

How to get Column Name With Zend DB

Comment: Perhaps you should describe a little bit what you're trying to do... Apikot's answer is a starting point though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is the correct answer, the older answers are wrong or outdated:

```
$cols = $table->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS);
```

Comment: rewrote your intro-text since SO doesn't know 'bumping' and questions/answers are not considered old. in fact SO is a wiki and updating it is one of the best things you can do! +1

Answer (score 8):

```
$metadata = $db->describeTable($tableName);
$columnNames = array_keys($metadata);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.list-describe

Comment: That's not really 100% correct as $metadata is an associative array ('column_name' => array()) of associative  arrays (one for each column of the table).

Comment: add schame's name  to  $db->describeTable($tableName, $schema); , i just had an error using oracle which takes old column names if i had changed them and had to specify the schema for it to return right column names

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer applies only to version < 2.
For current version of ZF (2.2) use:

```
$table = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('table', $Dbadapter, new Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\MetadataFeature());
$columns = $table->getColumns();
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#tablegateway-features
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.metadata.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the describeTable method

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```
$table->info('cols');
```