# How to get metadata result set using zend

Tags: zend-framework, metadata

How to get metadata from query result,.?
I wanna get the datatype of each column from my query result,.

Comment: What do you mean saying query result? `$table->fetchAll()` which returns `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` ? Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708782/how-to-get-column-name-with-zend-db

Comment: you right @singles , on that link, I can't find an answer for my question,.

Answer (score 1):

singles linked to a helpful post in his comment, but more specifically, here is how you can get the data type for a column from your table.

```
// $tbl is your Zend_Db_Table object
$info  = $tbl->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::METADATA); // get the table metadata, fetches it if it is not yet set

// get the data type for the "email_address" column
$type = $info['email_address']['DATA_TYPE']);
```

For each column in your table, you will have an array of data like so:

```
["column_name"] =>
    array(14) {
    ["SCHEMA_NAME"]=> NULL
    ["TABLE_NAME"]=> string(8) "accounts"
    ["COLUMN_NAME"]=> string(10) "account_id"
    ["COLUMN_POSITION"]=> int(1)
    ["DATA_TYPE"]=> string(9) "mediumint"
    ["DEFAULT"]=> NULL
    ["NULLABLE"]=> bool(false)
    ["LENGTH"]=> NULL
    ["SCALE"]=> NULL
    ["PRECISION"]=> NULL
    ["UNSIGNED"]=> bool(true)
    ["PRIMARY"]=> bool(true)
    ["PRIMARY_POSITION"]=> int(1)
    ["IDENTITY"]=> bool(true)
```

}